# Rails 3: How to submit form inside another model's show method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, routes

I have a page in pages#show. I created a messages form inside that page. When submitted I get this error "Routing Error No route matches [POST] /pages/9".

So it's a form inside another's model show page. In this case it's a form that will work with the Message model, inside a Page show view.

```
<%= form_for(@message, :url => page_path(@page)) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :content %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly what I wanted, but it'll do for now:
http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/

Answer (score 1):

You may **use AJAX** to send the request to the '/messages' path, then receive and display the errors without reloading the page, OR **change your routes** a little.

Define an additional route:

```
match "pages/:id", :via=>:post, :controller=>"pages", :action=>"create_message"
```

Then define the action `create_message` in similar way to usual `create` actions: if the message has been created, redirect to `/pages/:id`, and if there was an error, render the "show" action.

In case of error, you should also remember about returning proper HTTP status code when rendering the "show" view *(code 422 looks like a good one)*, and just make the "show" view aware of possible `@message` error messages.

I am not sure whether I like this way of creating messages *(a `POST /page/3/messages` looks like a better solution)*, but I am also not confident that this is a bad thing. ;-)

Comment: I though about AJAX but what if the website visitor has Javascript disabled? I need to rely on a non-Javascript solution first.

Comment: Then you are my hero! ;-) I said: "use AJAX **or** change your routes". The core answer is about non-AJAX solution. Of course, AJAX can be added to it without problem.

Answer (score 0):

The url specified:

url => page_path(@page)

Should be the route that is used to create messages.

You can run `rake routes` to find all the routes your app currently has.

Comment: If I don't specify it then, when there are validation errors, it'll take me to the messages#new action, when I really want to display the errors at pages#show.

Comment: check out aresen's answer. The answer is that once you are posting to the correct message creation url you should just render the show action from pages if there are errors

Answer (score 0):

You're giving it `:url => page_path(@page)`, which I assume gives you `/pages/9`.  Try just omitting the :url.  It should guess that this is a new message and take you to the right path.  Otherwise, if you want to be explicit, it should be something like `:url => message_path` (note no argument to `message_path` since a POST to a resource's root path is normally mapped to the create action).

Comment: If I omit it then when there are validation errors, it'll take me to the messages#new action, when I really want to display the errors at pages#show.

Comment: That's all a consequence of how your controller action is written.  If you want it to go back to the page, then you could use either `redirect :back` or figure it out using `request.referer`.